# uinavigation not working

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

My navigation controller not working.

I take a tabbar-based application now from app delegate. I want to add a navigationcontroller but it's not working.

```
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

I simply make an object of uinavigation controller and synthesize it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to add navigation Controller's view in the window, if you want to add a navigation controller in tabbar controller application.

See the below screen shot, you just need to select the tabbarcontroller in the IB and then from inspector window you can select class or particular tab item. Just make then navigation controller.

[image]

Comment: thanks saurabh..acutally my app is tab bar based..but after working on it i add a loging screen...so for that i need 2 set the navigation..hw can  i?

Comment: explain "need 2 set the navigation" in detail

Comment: in login view ...there are two fields if user have no id thn a other view of sign up ..

Comment: to implement this you just need one navigation controller. Just push the other sign up view if user have no id in navigation contorller

Comment: ok saurabh ..hav u skype id??/ add me there  vijay.adhikari05

Comment: my skype id - iamsaurabhsharma

Answer (score 0):

- Open MainWindow.xib.
- Under TabBarController you will see two view controllers.
- Delete both of the view controllers.
- Now, from the library add two navigation controllers under TabBatController.
- Now, open the inspector of the navigation controller and set its nib name and the class name.

i think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go through 
http://21gingerman.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/tutorial-and-sample-code-for-iphone-app-with-tab-bar-and-nav-bar/